# Implementing an infinite zoomable canvas in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtquick2

I am working on a project which requires an infinite surface to draw (splines and text) which also need to be scalable. The requirements for the "virtual surface" are:

- being able to scroll and move around the surface
- being able to dynamically resize its height (potentially to infinity but realistically up to 200000 "pixels")
- fixed width
- being able to draw vector paths, text and images
- scalable (using pinch to zoom. Also when the scale is changed all the vectors should be rendered at the new scale.
- being able to partially update regions of the surface

Looking at Qt, I have listed 3 main options to achieve this, but I am not entirely sure which of them would suit my needs best (or even if there is another alternative I have missed:

1. QGraphicsView, which would easily provide me with a scrollable viewport and has several built-in rendering strategies in order to achieve my goals (especially this https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#ViewportUpdateMode-enum). This would also automatically provide me with the tools to flick and resize the content. The only problem is that this class is part of Qt Widgets and I would really like to use QML).
2. Use `QQuickPaintedItem` as the viewport of my surface and dynamically paint it as the use scrolls and zooms. This would require me to update the viewport from QML (maybe with a combination of Flickable and PinchArea). However, I am not really sure if scrolling would be smooth enough with this option as the I would need redraw the item quite a lot to achieve 60fps. The situation could be mitigated by storing the already drawn regions in some QImage objects and then draw them when required (essentially a custom tile-based rendering solution which would require a lot of time of to implement properly).
3. Use `QQuickItem` instead of `QQuickPaintedItem` to achieve better performance, but then without QPainter drawing paths, shapes and text would quite difficult and would require a lot of work using the `QSG` classes.

Is there any other way to achieve this with Qt?

Comment: You could use OpenGL with QOpenGLWidget and only render in 2D. And with QOpenGLWidget you can also use QPainter two draw "easier" in 2D as with native OpenGL

Comment: The thing is that I would really like to avoid Qt Widgets, as (especially since the upcoming arrival of Qt6) I would like to stick with QML which is much more actively supported by the Qt Company (and it is really nice).

Comment: I found it easiest to do the drawing manually in the `paintEvent` method of my custom `QWidget`-subclass. Using `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`, one can implement panning and zooming, rotating, etc. It requires some math but if you want to avoid scroll bars and the concept of a `sceneRect`, you should avoid `QGraphicsView`. [code](https://github.com/pasbi/ommpfritt/tree/master/src/mainwindow/viewport). Of course, this is the `QWidget` -approach. I don't know if it works well with QML.

Comment: What are the requirements for the other parts of your application? Qt Widgets is not deprecated, it's just considered as 'done'/feature complete. QML is newer and more evolving technology, which doesn't imply it is the right technology to use in every case. I would stick to `QGraphicsView` (although I love QML too), if this is the only feature of your application.

Comment: @m7913d the core of the app will be the canvas. The other features needed are a custom toolbar, a customized GUI for opening files and good support for touch gestures (panning and kinetic scrolling).

Comment: Rather than `QGraphicsView`, you miiiight want to put a `QGraphicsScene` in it if it becomes your solution. Also, by " height ", I assume you are talking about the dimensions of the widget, not of the thing drawn in right, am I correct ? If so, I recommend you take a look at the `40 000 Chips` example of Qt (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem by drawing in a horizontal scrollable area of 64.000 pixel. To solve this, I use a ListView to divide the area in segments, 8.000 pixel each. The calculated segment count is used as model and the delegate is a QQuickPaintedItem for painting in C++. But this works also for a QML-Canvas.

```
ListView {
    id: graphicView
    anchors.fill: parent
    orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    spacing: 0
    // always repaint items on scroll
    reuseItems: false

    // the width of the scrollable area
    readonly property real displayWidth: 64000
    // define a max width for segmentation to avoid the contentWidth limitation of qml
    readonly property int segmentWith: 8000
    readonly property int segmentCount: Math.max(1, Math.round(displayWidth / segmentWith))
    onSegmentCountChanged: {
        console.log("OsziGraphic: displayWidth = " + displayWidth + ", segmentCount = " + segmentCount);
    }

    model: graphicView.segmentCount
    delegate:
        TestGraphicModel {
            height: ListView.view.height
            width: graphicView.displayWidth / graphicView.segmentCount
            segmentIndex: index
        }
}
```

In the backend I inherit from QQuickPaintedItem to add properties for the current segment index and the render area to draw in. I translate the rendered coordinates to draw as if the entire area is used.

```
void QQuickSegmentedPaintedItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    if (m_segmentIndex == -1)
        return;

     // calculate the current render rect inside the drawing area
     m_renderRect = QRect(m_segmentIndex * boundingRect().width(), 0, boundingRect().width(), boundingRect().height());

     // move the drawing area relative to the current render area
     painter->translate(-m_renderRect.left(), 0);
}
```

This works nicely for my needs. I hope you get the idea.

cheers!